# jQuery unbind an event for a specific element not the widget

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, widget

I created a jQuery widget that handles lazy loading of images. When the scroll bar changes each image is checked to see if it's visible, and if so that image is loaded.

My widget is something like this.

```
_create : function() {
    var self = this;
    if(self.isVisible())
    {
        self.load();
    }
    else
    {
        $(window).bind('scroll.'+self.widgetName,self.checkScroll);
    }
},
checkScroll : function() {
    var self = this;
    if(self.isVisible())
    {
        $(window).unbind('scroll.'+self.widgetName,self.checkScroll);
        self.load();
    }
},
```

If at first the image is visible in the viewport it's loaded, but if not the scrollbar event is binded to the widget's `checkScroll` function.

My problem is that the `unbind` is global for all widgets. So once the first lazy image is loaded none of the other images will get the `checkScroll` called.

How can I bind/unbind an event for a specific element that is using the widget, and not for all widgets?

Or am I doing this wrong, is there a better approach?

Comment: if the widgetname is unique, unbinding the namespaced scroll event should not unbind all the scroll events. Did you test that it does that?

Comment: widgetname is unique, but `_create` is called multiple times for each image. The event is binded to `$(window)` and not the widget's element. So the first `unbind` effects all of them, but you raise a point. If I append a unique string to the bind's name would this fix it?

Comment: this raises the question, how do I generate a unique string for each widget?

Comment: does your image have an ID? you could even just have a counter that increments when you call create and use that number.

Comment: ok, I'll just use a global counter. that should do the trick. thanks.